# Ubuntu 14.04 aborting OwnCloud installation even when pressed "Y" for continuation

Tags: installation, ubuntu-14.04, owncloud

I am trying to install OwnCloud on my Ubuntu 14.04. server, running LAMP.

I am using this tutorial to get it (https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-owncloud-7-on-ubuntu-14.04), but when I run `sudo apt-get update` I get:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://inverse.ca/ubuntu-v3/dists/trusty/trusty/binary-amd64Packages  401  Authorization Required [IP: 192.95.20.194 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://inverse.ca/ubuntu-v3/dists/trusty/trusty/binary-i386/ackages  401  Authorization Required [IP: 192.95.20.194 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones use instead.
```

Which I presume should I not be getting.

Then when I try running `sudo apt-get install owncloud` and get to:

`After this operation, 86.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y`

I get: `Abort.`

Anyone has an idea what I can try ? A bit lost here...

Comment: Seems your `/etc/apt/source.list` has an invalid host (inverse.ca shows a 401). Could you show the file so we can replace the bogus host?